# Specific answer to specific text

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a long time for a code that displays a different text depending on what you tipe. I didn't work at the app I wanted to make for a long time but *I think this is what I tried **(Remember I'm a begginer)***:

```
char text
cout << "Insert Text: " << text << endl;
if (text== "Stop")
{
 cout << "Ok. Bye!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: [I think you need to find yourself a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use cin to get something from the user. Also char means 'one single character'. Use strings instead

```
std::string text;
cout << "Insert Text: " << endl;
cin >> text;
if (text == "Stop")
{
    cout << "Ok. Bye!" << endl;
}
```